# Set selection on staggared gridview is not working for the first time?

Tags: android, gridview

I want my etsy's staggered gridview to set selection at the middle of all elements like if data is 100 then gridview should set it to 50th position.It does work if i scroll it and then call but it does not work for first time when data gets added.

I have tried several solutions here like clearing focus and then requestfromtouch method but nothing helps.Here is my code -:

```
class LoadDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
       // my code here
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        if(isTopListLoaded) {
            productDetailModelArrayList.addAll(0,productDetailModels);
        } else {
            productDetailModelArrayList.addAll(productDetailModels);
        }
        final int scrollPosition = gridView.getFirstVisiblePosition() + AppConstants.API_DATA_LIMIT;

        if(productDetailModelArrayList.size() == productDetailModels.size()) {
            //doesn't work here
            gridView.setSelection(productDetailModels.size());
        } else {
            // works here
            if(gridView.getColumnWidth() <= getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels) {
                gridView.setSelection(scrollPosition/2);
            } else {
                gridView.setSelection(scrollPosition);
            }
        }
        homeScreenAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it work.

Here is the solution i found https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid/issues/135

Answer (score 0):

If you're using StaggeredGridView of Etsy, it does not support set Selection at the moment. Here is issue
https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid/issues/34